# Dúvida - Visual Studio Exportar/Importar Projeto

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Estou com problemas na importação de projetos no VS 2015. O projeto foi feito em uma versão anterior da IDE e quando importo ele o mesmo não vem com os componentes corretamente adicionados, necessitando adicionar um a um.

Isso é o correto ou tem que seguir alguma especificação na exportação para embutir tudo junto?

Existe algum procedimento padrão/boa prática para tal tarefa?

Comment: Não sei que tipo de projeto é o seu, eu já "exportei" projetos `forms`, `service`, apenas clicando com o botão direito no projeto e abrindo com o VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando a importação não faz tudo sozinho pode significar que os arquivos descritores de projeto não estão exatamente como o interpretador esperaria ou mesmo não estão nos caminhos corretos, no caso de múltiplos módulos. Já tive inúmeros problemas em importar projetos e sempre sobra um retrabalho manual. Também já tive de recriar projetos do zero e inserir os módulos em casos mais críticos.
Portanto não se assuste, pois o caminho nem sempre é livre de falhas ao importar projetos.